# When the screen rotates, the layout changes

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a project and when I start it on emulator the layout is in order, but when i rotate the screen, the layout changes. For example when the project starts the textview1 is on top of textview2, but afeter I rotate the screeen, textview1 and textview2 are on the same place. how can i handle this? when the screen rotates. i want the layout to adapt to the device. for example it is installed on a tablet. the layout is still the same. and when it is installed on smartphones and the screen rotates i want that the layout is still the same.

Comment: What do you want to do? freeze your layout on rotation or change view?

Comment: do you want to keep the screen in portait mode even if the screen is rotated?

Comment: u need to create different layout from both oriantations google it will get the answer

Comment: You will need to add to separate layout files for `landscape` and `portrait` orientation mode...

Answer (score 3):

Create two folder for your layout : first is `layout-land` and other is `layout-port`, create two different xml file with same name and according to landscape or portrait view each for`layout-land` and for `layout-port` design your layout (xml file) 
Device will automatically take the xml file as per the orientation.

More info here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.

```
---layout-land(folder name)
   ---yourlayout.xml  // same name file with design according to landscape mode
---layout-port(folder name)
   ---yourlayout.xml  // same name file with design according to portrait mode
```

Comment: I have another question. Is it really a folder or just and xml file?

Comment: I've done that already. But when i restart eclipse. my classes had errors in this line. setContentView(R.layout.mylayout.xml)

Comment: Make sure you don't have this in your imports: import android.R; but import your_application_packagename.R;

Comment: i've done that already. import com.example.login1.R and still i has the same error

Comment: @KarlCaday did u try setContentView(R.layout.mylayout); type R.layout. and then Ctrl+Space

Comment: is says no default proposals

Comment: @KarlCaday in eclipse select Windows->Show View->Problems are there any feedbacks? if so please post.

Comment: the errors are the ones i called from the xml to the class.. for example there's an edittext on my xml. i should call it on my class in order to use it. and that's the problem. it says it cannot be resolved as a field

Answer (score 1):

you have to create layout files for each screen sizes and orientation

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: @KarlCaday of course. create this folders. copy your orjinal layout file to each folder. when editing your xml in grafical layout tab, change screen size . this way you can see layout output each screen size. and edit them.

Comment: I've done that already. But when i restart eclipse. my classes had errors in this line. setContentView(R.layout.mylayout.xml)

Comment: @KarlCaday try setContentView(R.layout.mylayout)

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you only have one layout folder, your layout should be the same in landscape and portrait mode both on tablets or phones because android can't find another layout to use.

Android system uses specific layout if a condition is met for the device:

**e.g** if device is in landscape it tries to load the layout with name [some-layout.xml] from folder "layout-land",  but if it can't find your [some-layout.xml] file inside that folder
or the "layout-land" folder does not even exist, it uses the [some-layout.xml] layout in your default "layout" folder.

> So i believe that there must be a problem in your layout file that
>   places the TextViews on the same place in landscape mode.

Otherwise, if you want a different layout in portrait and different in landscape, 
create a new folder in your resources with the name "layout-land" and add inside a copy of your layout and add how you want your textviews to be placed diffrently in landscape mode.

Comment: please refer to the answer of BaZinga on top. any suggestions?

Comment: yes it is because you have used this "R.layout.mylayout.xml" you don't need to add .xml to the end, android knows that you want an xml file, you just need to point to name of the layout e.g setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);

Comment: oh sorry. mybad. i dont have there the .xml on the end. after I copy the xml files on the folder layout-land and layout-port the error starts. setContentView(R.layout.mylayout) and the red line(which indicates error) is on layout

Comment: First Check that you have imported the correct R from your project and not the android.R, and then try to clean build your project in case the R class has not been autogenerated.

Comment: what do you mean imported the corerct R? i pur this on every class.. import com.example.login1.R

Comment: post an example code of your activity and the layout in your question

Answer (score 0):

you should use relative-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:text="RED"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:text="ORANGE"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and if you want to handle change in configuration add

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" to your Manifest
```